# How do I position a download button directly beneath an image on the right side

Tags: html, css, button

I have been diligently working on the development of a website that features a header and an image within the body. However, I encountered a few problems when attempting to position a download button directly beneath the image on the right side.
If you want to see my code it's on my GitHub! https://github.com/moseskbalunywa/Stackoverflow

I tried this solution:

```css
.img-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.image-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

#downloadButton {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  background-color: #9C78E4;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
}

#downloadButton:hover {
  background-color: #584089;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container">
  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <img id="plattegrond" src="images/plattegrond.jpg" class="center" />
    <button id="downloadButton">Download</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Despite expecting the download button to appear directly beneath the image on the right, it unexpectedly centered below the image instead.

I tried another solution:

```css
.img-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.image-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

#plattegrond {
  width: 50%;
}

#downloadButton {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  background-color: #9C78E4;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
}

#downloadButton:hover {
  background-color: #584089;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container">
  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <img id="plattegrond" src="images/plattegrond.jpg" class="center" />
    <button id="downloadButton">Download</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

In this attempt, I adjusted the width of the image and added a right margin to the download button. However, the image became excessively large, covering approximately 95% of the webpage.

So I tried one last solution:

```css
.img-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.image-wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

#plattegrond {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#downloadButton {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  background-color: #9C78E4;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
}

#downloadButton:hover {
  background-color: #584089;
}
```

While attempting a different solution, the image size reduced, but it became somewhat smaller than intended.

Throughout this process, I sought guidance from ChatGPT, considering various strategies to achieve a desired outcome.

Sources: ChatGPT

Answer (score 0):

You could do this.

`display: inline-flex` makes the container only as big as its contents, rather than the full width of its container.
`flex-direction: column;` orients the items in the container from top to bottom rather than left to right.
`align-items: flex-end;` aligns things in the container to the right when flex-direction is column.

For more information on flex, [check the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#display_flex).

I also removed your `position` styles from the button since those would have caused the button to appear over top the image instead of below it.

```css
.image-wrapper {
  display: -webkit-inline-box;
  display: -ms-inline-flexbox;
  display: inline-flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-align: end;
  -ms-flex-align: end;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-wrapper">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/150" />
  <button>Download</button>
</div>
```

Comment: It doesnt work it just places the download button in in the bottom left corner with a image of a cat. I didn't ask for a cat image.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed you were using a webkit browser. I've added prefixes for the others. The cat is a placeholder so you can see what the result looks like in the snippet. Relative image paths don't work in code snippets, that's why the image in yours is broken.

Comment: Explaining what the answer's code does differently from the OP's code, and why, is what distinguishes good answers from bad on this site...